# Adjusting the table headers on Kintone JSedit

Tags: javascript

So far, my main problem is that I am trying to adjust a table on Kintone.
I have been able to access the contents of the table (when you add table elements to it, you can see the colors changing, however the headers themselves do not seem to change).

Currently, I am using Kintone (Cybozu), however since it is using JSEdit, I think the problem can be solved with Javascript knowledge (which I very much do not have).

What do I want to do?

(please see the attached pictures)
Center, bold, and other adjustments to those headers.
If my code is completely wrong, please do ignore it and any code that will help this situation would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Fvo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CR9T.png)

Answer (score 1):

From the code you shared, you get a table element as kintone.app.record.getFieldElement(field code of the table), but as for the table, it contains multiple elements.
Therefore, as with other fields, changing the style.backgroundColor of the acquired element will not change the color.

Could you try and apply the following CSS to get the desired process?
The header will be yellow with the CSS below, so please specify the color as desired.

```
.body-record-print .show-subtable-gaia th {
background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I will try as soon as possible!

I do have a few questions.
You mentioned that the above is CSS, but the language being used for this would be Javascript.
As I do not know how it works, if I were to copy and paste the above code into the JSEdit, would it work just as well?